# In which table in MySQL in prestashop, can i find the field Displayed text when in stock

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I'm trying to find in Prestashop 1.6 (in MySQL)the table which contains the field for "Displayed text when in-stock".

Could anyone tell me where can i find that field and in which table in MySQL?

Any suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems like your title is different from the actual question. The title asks for a table name but the question is about changing the status for all products. Please make sure that the title reflects your actual question.

Comment: Yes, i think that if i find the table a can make the attribute to "available", but i cant find that field. But if anyone else has a same problem i would like to know how they solve the problem...

Comment: Apologies for being blunt but your question doesn't make sense. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will probably give you ideas of how to ask so that you get a useful answer.

Comment: ok my friend, propably you have write!! I'm not very specific, thanks for your advise

Comment: write something wierd like 'abcdef' and then search all the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in `ps_product_lang`, the column name is `available_now`
If you want to edit, don't forget to take into account the `id_lang` column

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` SET `available_now` = 'English Content' where `id_lang` = 1;

UPDATE `ps_product_lang` SET `available_now` = 'French Content' where `id_lang` = 2;
```

Supposing English and French have `id_lang` 1 and 2 respectively

Answer (score 1):

AS UnLoCo has said, the table is something like: ps_product_lang 
"ps_" is the database prefix which you might have changed in your instance.

That table has got two columns;

- available_now: shows when stock is available
- available_later: shows when stock is zero or negative.

FYI: available quantity can be accessed in different ways depending on advance stock management feature. if not using that feature; this table: "ps_"stock_available has got the available quantity for the products.